# How to connect with node.js to mongoDB without running additional command windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've read this tutorial:
http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

in part 3, the author explains how to connect to MongoDB, but his way requires running of separate command windows.
I want to know if there is a way to connect the DB i've created, from the application code, without running other command windows.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need running win commands to work with Nodejs/MongoDB u just need a normal *connection* string, like the one you found with MySQL and Postgre.

Answer (score 0):

The `mongod` command is used to start the Mongo server. To connect a db client to it from your application, you can take a look at [this example](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/quick-start/) from the official MongoDB documentation (scroll to "Connect to MongoDB"). You simply need to do something like

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/nodetest1';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected succesfully to server");

  db.close();
});
```